# Can't clone a Github repo after setting http.sslCAInfo

Tags: git, ssl

I had to manage a private git repo, so I created a .pem and set http.sslCAInfo to the path of the .pem. But now I can't clone from Github's repos anymore:

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker/': server
>   certificate verification failed. CAfile:
>   /home/marco/sources/git_certs/cert.pem CRLfile: none

What's the default value of http.sslCAInfo? I tried to set it to "" but now I get

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also run the following command to get the "right" directory that openssl is using (under Linux/Git Bash). This outputs the directory in quotes, so you shouldn't need to do any special magic to handle spaces and could pipe it right to another command.

`openssl version -d | awk '{ print $2 }'`

So you could fix your git config with:

`git config --global http.sslCAInfo $(openssl version -d | awk '{ print $2 }')`

Comment: You have to `sed` it a little, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I forgot it presented the environment variable name in the output, I'll see about fixing that for future visitors.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Thanks for the heads up, should be much nicer now.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I solved with

```
git config --global http.sslCAInfo /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

You can configure only the current repo with

```
git config http.sslCAInfo path/to/local.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had same problem with **SourceTree** on Windows.

1. Not recommended, but easy solution:

   ```
   Disable certificate check
   git config --system http.sslverify false
   ```
2. Add your certificate to ca-bundle.crt 
   (it is located at: c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\mingw32\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt)

In case if you already set http.sslCAInfo to your self signed certificate and would like to set back to original one:

```
    git config --global http.sslCAInfo /mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the .gitconfig file at the root of my user account in windows.  you may have to turn on 'show hidden files' in windows explorer or linux for .(dot) files.

and then I erased these 2 lines to restore sslCAInfo to default:

```
[http]
    sslCAInfo = *whatever you set here*
```

Then I recommend following these instructions https://mattferderer.com/fix-git-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-windows

basically exporting a certificate as a base64 certificate, finding ca-bundle.crt within your git install, edit that file by copying the text from the exported base64 certificate to the bottom of ca-bundle.crt.